# Using \footfullcite{ref}, how can I get the subscript to not be a clickable link?

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, biber, superscripts

The following code works fine except I don't want any `\footfullcite` superscripts to be clickable links.  How can I get the superscripts to just be a normal superscripts?

```
\documentclass{paper}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{
    shivers,
    author = {Olin Shivers},
    title  = {Dissertation Advice},
    url    = {http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/shivers/diss-advice.html}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\verb+cite\footfullcite{shivers}+ gives cite\footfullcite{shivers}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! And thank you very much for the nice ans concise MWE. I have to admit, though, that I don't quite understand your question. What "link" are you referring to? The click-able area `hyperref` produces around the footnote number (and if that is the case do you want to disable linking for cite footnotes only or all footnotes)? The URL in the citation?

Comment: I don't want the click-able area hyperref produces around the footnote number for all citations.  Thanks---sorry my original question wasn't clear.  @Guido

Comment: What do you want to happen to "normal" footnote markers (those that don't come from a `\footcite`, but a `\footnote`)? If all links should be turned off `hyperfootnotes=false` in `hyperref`'s options might do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the link by adding the following

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\iffootnote{\clearfield{url}}{}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use \usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref} to remove the clickable link from the superscript to the footnote citation at the bottom of the page.

Use \AtEveryCitekey{\iffootnote{\clearfield{url}}{}} to remove the URL field from the footnote citation at the bottom of the page.